# Querying an api with android spring?

Tags: android, spring, rest

I'm pretty new to both android and RESTful resources (been learning Rails and RoboSpice). I have a rails api setup correctly and for starters I'd like to pass a user name and password to the api and get a user model object back. I've been looking at the docs and examples and it's been pretty confusing. I was hoping someone could give me a quick example or point me at a good tutorial. Just for a test case, could someone walk me through this snippet and how could I adjust it to query?:

```
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.setAcceptEncoding(ContentCodingType.IDENTITY);
HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders);

// Create a new RestTemplate instance
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

// Add the String message converter
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

// Make the HTTP GET request, marshaling the response to a String
ResponseEntity<User> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, User.class);
```

Also, specifically what do the headers do? and how do I set up a class to recieve the response? i.e. User.class to receive a User model. That part confuses me the most >.< It seems disorganized..

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple example:

```
   private static final String TAG = "HTTP CLIENT: ";

public String login(String User,String Pass){
    Log.d(TAG, "Login Attempt!!!");
    String result = "Empty!!!";
    String url = "http://somehost.somedomain.com:8080/login?email="+User+"&password="+Pass;
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    try {
        result = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class, "");

    }catch (Exception e){
        result = e.getMessage();

        Log.d(TAG, "Exception Message: "+e.getMessage()+" "+e.getCause());
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Token: "+result);

    return result;
}
```

in regards to the Headers they are use to set the type of content that you will handle, for example JSON or XML data.

Comment: Ah, I see. thanks. The other thing I'm stumped on his I can get a model belonging to another model. Like I mentioned If user has many: shirts. How would I get the shirts model and set up a shirt class to recieve it?

Comment: not sure if I understood correctly but it depends what is comming from the target. If you get an object, you can accept object and those will come with all the data you are looking for. but it mainly depends on what the target is reponding to your request.